# How to remove all blank pages from already loaded word document using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I have a word document generated/loaded using apache poi and want to remove all blank pages from the document. Question is how to identify all blank pages and remove them.

Comment: One cannot determine what text is on what page on a Word document from the Word file. A Word document consists of a stream of body elements flowing over the pages. Only those body elements are stored in the file. The Word document would must be rendered to determine what text is on what page. But `apache poi`does not rendering in `XWPF`. Only thing one could do is to remove all explicit page breaks. After that no blank page will be present. But then there might be page breaks other than before.

Comment: thanks for the response. Is it possible to write macro which will execute automatically after word document is open by user and delete blank pages ??? please guide.

Comment: I don't know, whether Word VBA is able detecting and removing blank pages. It should be able to, because VBA runs when Word has rendered the document already. But this is another question having other tags (`ms-word` `vba`). Check answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-word%5D+%5Bvba%5D+%2Bdelete%2Bblank+%2Bpage. If nothing of that answers your issue, then ask a new question.